# Ejecutar un script de python con node.js

Tags: python, nodejs

Como hago para ejecutar un script de python con node.js? Intenté hacerlo con esta forma pero no me funciono.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const express = require('express')
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

client.on('message', message => {
    
    console.log(message.content);
    if (message.content.includes("!find")) {
        //Aqui es donde no se como ejecutar el archivo D:
        const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["finder.py", message]);
    }
});

client.login('//Aqui va el token');
```

Aquí esta el script de python:

```
#Imports
import sys
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook


#Agarra el nombre
nombre = sys.argv[1]
nombre.replace("!find ","")

#Busca el nombre y lo imprime
databases = 1
url1 = "//Aqui va la url de la webhook"
for i in range(14):
    archivo = open("db-" + str(databases) + ".txt", "r")
    for line in archivo.readlines():
        if nombre in line:
            webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=url1, content=line)
            response = webhook.execute()
    databases = databases + 1
```

Lo que quiero hacer es mandar la variable (message) de Js al script de Python con un argumento.
Si alguien es tan amable de ayudar se lo agradeceria. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probablemente un problema con ambos paths: a Python y al script.

Comment: Hola, como puedo arreglar el path para poder conectarlos?

Comment: Escribiendo el path completo al interprete Python y al script.